# Clojure Lang Arity Exception

Tags: clojure

I've been trying to implement Spam Classifier. I wrote one function to get some probability but when I call this function with two arguments I get clojure.lang.ArityException "Wrong number of args passed to function". Here is my function:

```
(defn weightedprob
  [f cat]
  (let [weight 1
        ap 0.5
        basicprob (atom 0)
        totals (atom 0)
        bp (atom 0)]
    (swap! basicprob #(fprob f cat))
    (swap! totals #(reduce + (vals (get @fc f))))
    (swap! bp #(/ (+ (* weight ap) (* totals basicprob)) (+ weight totals)))
    bp))
```

And here is the call:

```
(weightedprob "money" "good")
```

It works now. If you have better idea how to implement this function, I would be happy to see that. Here is version that works:

```
(defn weightedprob
  [f cat]
   (let [weight 1
   ap 0.5
   basicprob (atom 0)
   totals (atom 0)
   bp (atom 0)]
  (reset! basicprob (fprob f cat))
  (reset! totals (reduce + (vals (get @fc f))))
  (reset! bp (/ (+ (* weight ap) (* @totals @basicprob)) (+ weight 
  @totals)))
  @bp))
```

The function in Python I have been implementing looks as folows:

```
  def weightedprob(self,f,cat,prf,weight=1.0,ap=0.5):    
      # Calculate current  probability    
      basicprob=prf(f,cat)
      # Count the number of times this feature has appeared in    
      # all categories    
      totals=sum([self.fcount(f,c) for c in self.categories()])
      # Calculate the weighted average    
      bp=((weight*ap)+(totals*basicprob))/(weight+totals)    
      return bp
```

This is from Collective Intelligence book, chapter 6, Document Filtering

Function without atoms:

```
(defn weightedprob1
 [f cat]
  (let [weight 1
        ap 0.5
        basicprob (fprob f cat)
        totals (reduce + (vals (get @fc f)))
        bp (/ (+ (* weight ap) (* totals basicprob)) (+ weight totals))]
  bp))
```

Comment: In the functions that you've given `swap!`, you aren't using the argument provided. It's expecting that your `#()` function will take an argument (`%`). Did you mean `(reset! basicprob (fprob f cat))`? It doesn't even look like you should be using atoms here though. If you post a [mcve], we can suggest how this should be written. In its current form though, it's not clear what it's supposed to be doing.

Comment: Things like `(* totals basicprob)` look complelty wrong.  At least you have to deref (e.g. `@totals`) to get the value out.  This code has very bad smells; like someone told you to use atoms for mutating data and now you use them everywhere -- this code looks as un-clojury as it gets to me.  As already suggested, please provide more information about the big picture here, if this is really the right route you are taking here.

Comment: How would you solve this function without atoms? I can only solve this directly in let expression or with atoms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your original problem was caused by `swap!` expecting a function that takes a single argument. You were supplying a function that didn't take any arguments though, thus the error.

The corrected code would be what you've already posted:

```
(defn weightedprob [f cat]
  (let [weight 1
        ap 0.5
        basicprob (atom 0)
        totals (atom 0)
        bp (atom 0)]
    (reset! basicprob (fprob f cat))
    (reset! totals (reduce + (vals (get @fc f))))
    (reset! bp (/ (+ (* weight ap) (* @totals @basicprob)) (+ weight @totals)))
    @bp))
```

This doesn't require atoms at all though. Atoms are mainly just used for managing data between threads. You don't need any kind of mutation at all here. Just continue using `let`:

```
(defn weightedprob [f cat]
  (let [weight 1
        ap 0.5
        basicprob (fprob f cat)
        totals (reduce + (vals (get @fc f)))]
   (/ (+ (* weight ap) (* totals basicprob)) (+ weight totals))))
```

And it's not clear what `fc` is, but it likely doesn't need to be an atom either.

Comment: Yes, I did something similar. You can check above. 
"The fc variable will store the counts for different features in different classifications. For example:
{'python': {'bad': 0, 'good': 6}, 'the': {'bad': 3, 'good': 3}} ". In this example word "python" has appeared in six good documents and hasn't appeared in bad documents.